# What is the difference between using 叫　and 叫做　？

Tags: difference, word

I understand for the most part, (perhaps not as a causative word like shi, rang, bei etc ENTIRELY..) how to use 叫　and when trying to see the difference between 叫　and 称为　　, I noticed that people compared 称为　with 叫做　, a term I had not actually seen before.

My question is, what is the difference between the inclusion/exclusion of the word 做　in 叫做　?

Also, as a bonus, does any one want to validate my research, and let me know if 称为　vs 叫做 is a matter of more formal writing and not convention ?

Or is it a more spoken vs written distinction as I beleeve the distinction between 叫做　and 叫作　　exists as ?  Is this distinction only in Cantonese?  I wonder because my Mandarin ABC input keyboard on Windows doesn't recognize the latter as a compound word.

Thank you!

Comment: 叫：be called 你叫什么[名字]？ NP+叫+NP，NP's name is NP, people introducing themselves say 我叫。。。
这叫拖拉机  他不知道什么叫干净.
  叫做：be called, be known as,人类叫做理性动物,将(把)人类叫做理性动物,  把...称为, 把...命名为,他被人们叫做收藏家,

Comment: Okay, I understand to a certain extent.  I am unfamiliar with the 把 structure in its entirety, so I am a little confused.  I like your examples though.  I also understand about 命名..I guess if you do not use 被　it implies that the speaker named the object??  Example:  強渦流被稱為Maelstrom ..if remove 被　does it still make sense?  But the meaning changes?

Comment: 強渦流被稱為。。。 or 强涡流叫（叫做，称为）。。。all seem possible, in particular 被  with 称为 seems unnecessary, more examples: 商品的普通销售价格称为市价,他才可称为老师,各种物质，不论它是什么，都是由一些称为分子的很小的粒子构成的（notional passive, 被 :formal passive, anyhow frequent use of 被 may be a modern feature)

Comment: What did you mean by NP, noun particle?  I was confused, but, I decided to ask instead of guessing..

Comment: 我在后面叫你，但是你没有听到。 As for that sentence, can one omit the 有 in 没有?  I know it is somewhat off topic, but, it really will help me.  Thank you.

Comment: NP=noun phrase, including pronouns, 有 can be omitted, this has been answered on this site before

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean here ?? 把...称为, 把...命名为,  oh..do you mean there is a missing part of a clause??

Comment: "..." stands for the object of the 把-sentence which can be any NP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **叫**= **to call** / **be called**

我叫彼得 could mean:

1. 'I call Peter (e.g. I make a phone call to Peter) '
2. 'I am called Peter (my name is Peter)'

> **叫做** = **be called as**

我叫做彼得 = I am called as Peter (my name is Peter) - *no ambiguity here*

> **称**= [1] [v] **call**; **name**; term; address as
>   [2] [v] say; state; express; claim

- 人称(为) = people call (him/ her/ it) as
- 自称(为) = call oneself as / self proclaim as
- 称为 = be called as

Abe Shudug wrote:

> *Could you please also clarify how it becomes him/her/it with 人称为 ? Maybe an example sentence..do you mean 他　她　它　　ｎｅｅｄ　ｔｏ　ｂｅ　ａｄｄｅｄ?　　Ｏｒ　为　serves that function ??*

**Some examples:**

(他/她)被人稱為天下無敵 = (他/她)人稱天下無敵

*被人稱為 is often shortened to 人稱*

(他/她)自稱為天下無敵 = (他/她)自稱天下無敵

*自稱為 if often shortened to 自稱*

[他/她/它] is the object, which is needed in a complete sentence.

为 acts as the conjunction 'as'*(without antecedent) in the degree, manner*

> 称为 is more literal;  叫做 is more colloquial

Comment: What about the difference between 叫做　and 叫作　, I saw the latter on MDBG.net   I am not sure if that has an actual usage.  Cheers :)

Comment: 我在后面叫你，但是你没有听到。 As for that sentence, can one omit the 有 in 没有?  I know it is somewhat off topic, but, it really will help me.  Thank you.

Comment: Could you please also clarify how it becomes him/her/it with 人称为 ?  Maybe an example sentence..do you mean 他　她　它　　ｎｅｅｄ　ｔｏ　ｂｅ　ａｄｄｅｄ?　　Ｏｒ　为　serves that function ??

Comment: See the edition at the bottom of my post